# view web service on local host in web browser

Tags: web-services

I would like brwose my published web service on the localhost. But if I try to open this `http://localhost:12800/api/WSTest2/v1.0.0` link in my web browser. I see HTTP 404- Error.
Do I something wrong?

Comment: from what programming language?

Comment: Actually I put this url in browser and try to open it